# Type families causes ambiguous variable error

Tags: haskell, type-families

Use case: I'm writing a game in a ghcjs frontend and a backend that use essentially the same state so that I can encode the rules of the game on both sides and communicate with changes in state.  To that end a gamestate would look like

```
data GameState = GameState {
  gameTurn :: Int,            -- | Everyone sees
  gamePhase :: GamePhase,     -- | this
  boardState :: BoardState,   -- | stuff
  -- a lot more stuff everyone can see, followed by
  usHand :: [Card],
  ussrHand :: [Card]
}
```

Where each player is represented by us and ussr.  Each player has a hand and from the server perspective it is omnicient, and knows every card in both player's hands.  But from the us player's perspective, gamestate looks more like this

```
data GameState = GameState {
  -- public stuff
  usHand :: [Card],
  ussrHand :: Int
}
```

That is, he can see his own hand, but he can only see how many cards his opponent has.  An observer sees even less.  The rules of the game are complex and there are a lot of things that can happen so it'd be great to encode the rules once, such that rules which affect a player's hand, such as dealing new cards, forcing a player to show a card of a type, etc, would affect each hand in the way that is appropriate depending who they are.  To that end, I ended up writing the following using type families, which doesn't work

```
{-# LANGUAGE  TypeFamilies, RankNTypes #-}
module Test where

data Card = Card
data BoardState = BoardState
data GamePhase = GamePhase
data Country
data Player = PUS | PUSSR

data US
data USSR
data Observer
data Server

data Private = Private Int
data Public = Public [Card]

class HandType a where
  type USHand   a :: *
  type USSRHand a :: *
  toUS :: Public -> USHand a
--   toUSSR :: Public -> USSRHand a -- TODO

instance HandType Server where
  type USHand Server = Public
  type USSRHand Server = Public
  toUS (Public cs) = Public cs

instance HandType US where
  type USHand US = Public
  type USSRHand US = Private
  toUS (Public cs) = Public cs

instance HandType USSR where
  type USHand USSR = Private
  type USSRHand USSR = Public
  toUS (Public cs) = Private (length cs)

instance HandType Observer where
  type USHand Observer = Private
  type USSRHand Observer = Private
  toUS (Public cs) = Private (length cs)

data GameState a = GameState {
  gameTurn :: Int,            -- | Everyone sees
  gamePhase :: GamePhase,     -- | this
  boardState :: BoardState,   -- | stuff

  usHand :: USHand a,
  ussrHand :: USSRHand a
}

data Event a =
    PlaceInfluence Player Int Country -- | Most plays don't affect
  | PlayCard Player Card              -- | either hand
  | DealCards (USHand a) (USSRHand a) -- | This one does

-- Works
obsEvents :: [Event US]
obsEvents = [PlayCard PUS Card, PlayCard PUSSR Card, DealCards (Public [Card]) (Private 3)]

-- Works
serverEvents :: [Event Server]
serverEvents = [PlayCard PUS Card, PlayCard PUSSR Card, DealCards (Public [Card, Card]) (Public [Card])]

-- The server must send out the gamestate modified for the player's consumption.
-- serverToPlayerGS :: GameState Server -> GameState a
serverToPlayerGS (GameState turn phase bs us ussr) =
  GameState turn phase bs (toUS us) undefined -- | <- Doesn't work (line 75)

-- serverToPlayerEvent :: Event Server -> Event a
serverToPlayerEvent (PlaceInfluence p amt c) = PlaceInfluence p amt c
serverToPlayerEvent (PlayCard p c) = PlayCard p c
serverToPlayerEvent (DealCards us ussr) =
  DealCards (toUS us) undefined -- | <- Doesn't work (line 78)
```

The error on both lines 75 and 78 are both something along the lines of

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘USHand a’
            with actual type ‘USHand a0’
NB: ‘USHand’ is a type function, and may not be injective
The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
Relevant bindings include
  serverToPlayerGS :: GameState Server -> GameState a
    (bound at src/Test4.hs:74:1)
In the fourth argument of ‘GameState’, namely ‘(toUS us)’
In the expression: GameState turn phase bs (toUS us) undefined
```

Or if I omit a type declaration

```
Could not deduce (USHand a0 ~ USHand a1)
from the context (HandType a1,
                  USHand a1 ~ USHand a,
                  USHand t ~ Public)
  bound by the inferred type for ‘serverToPlayerGS’:
             (HandType a1, USHand a1 ~ USHand a, USHand t ~ Public) =>
             GameState t -> GameState a
  at src/Test4.hs:(74,1)-(75,45)
NB: ‘USHand’ is a type function, and may not be injective
The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
Expected type: USHand a
  Actual type: USHand a0
When checking that ‘serverToPlayerGS’ has the inferred type
  serverToPlayerGS :: forall t a a1.
                      (HandType a1, USHand a1 ~ USHand a, USHand t ~ Public) =>
                      GameState t -> GameState a
Probable cause: the inferred type is ambiguous
```

I see some other answers on the site that are similar, but I'm not sure how the fixes explained would ultimately lead to the answer I'm hoping for, which is a way to write serverToPlayerGS and serverToPlayerEvent in ways that typecheck and are useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your type family is not injective: knowing that `USHand a` is `Private` for instance doesn't tell you exactly what `a` is: it could be `USSR` but it could also be `Observer` because both instances declare:

```
type USHand USSR = Private
type USHand Observer = Private
```

Because the function `toUS` has type `Public -> USHand a`, the `a` has to be somehow guessed and we just saw that it was not possible.

In order to fix this, you are going to need to introduce proxies. A proxy is a simple data type defined as:

```
data Proxy a = Proxy
```

If you have a function `f :: F a` for which Haskell is not able to guess the `a`, you can turn it into an `f :: Proxy a -> F a` in order to be able to specify at the call site which `a` you mean by writing for instance `f (Proxy :: Proxy Int)` in the case where you want `a` to be `Int`.

You'll need scoped type variables because the `a` you'll use with `toUs` will come from the type annotation of your function. So you should add these two lines at the top of your file:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
import Data.Proxy
```

And then change the type of `toUS` from `Public -> USHand a` to:

```
toUS :: Proxy a -> Public -> USHand a
```

Don't forget to add a dummy argument `_` to all your instance declarations of `toUs`. Finally, you can patch your definition of `serverToPlayerGS` like so:

```
serverToPlayerGS :: forall a. HandType a => GameState Server -> GameState a
serverToPlayerGS (GameState turn phase bs us ussr) =
  GameState turn phase bs (toUS (Proxy :: Proxy a) us) undefined
```

Comment: That totally works.  Thanks a lot!  Also I heard that a future release of ghc the Proxy type may not be necessary.  Does anyone have any references to any info regarding that?

Comment: @mindreader, Yes that's the `TypeApplication` extension. It will land in GHC 8, which already has a release candidate available. https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/TypeApplication